# Angular module federation site not able to deploy in production properly (404 error when calling remotes)

Tags: web-deployment, micro-frontend, angular-module-federation

I attempted millions of things already, so help me please.

---

By following this documentation:
https://nx.dev/recipes/module-federation/faster-builds#production-build-and-deployment-with-nx-cloud

I want to simulate same exercise, create a host and 3 remotes, and deploy the 4 applications on my LOCAL IIS, each one of the apps with a different port. (like if all of them would be in a different CND and deployed independently)

---

A) I created a MF site with a few characteristics:

1. host (local port:4201, prod port:6001)
2. remote shop (local port:4202, prod port:6002)
3. remote cart (local port:4203, prod port:6003)
4. remote about(local port:4204, prod port:6004)

B) To simulate PROD, I created on my Local IIS, all the webapps with the mentioned PROD ports, like

- host:6001
- shop:6002
- cart:6003
- about:6004

C) I configured as per the documentation, the following in the config prod (note same port for all):

```
module. Exports = withModuleFederation({
  ...moduleFederationConfig,
  remotes: [
    ['shop', 'http://localhost:6001/shop'],
    ['cart', 'http://localhost:6001/cart'],
    ['about', 'http://localhost:6001/about'],
  ],
});
```

> which will be incorrect, the console will throw error like
> "localhost:6001/shop/remoteEntry.mjs net::ERR_ABORTED 404"
>
> This has sense to me, because the port+folder doesn't exists,
> so is not correct to search the remoteEntry on that URL. I assume the example meant to
> have all the remotes under the same site, which beaks the purpose of MF to be deployed in
> different sites.
> In other words, the documentation is not correct for this example.

Based on the error, I modified the config to be like this:

```
module. Exports = withModuleFederation({
  ...moduleFederationConfig,
  remotes: [
    ['shop', 'http://localhost:6002'],
    ['cart', 'http://localhost:6003'],
    ['about', 'http://localhost:6004'],
  ],
});
```

> This has more sense now, the 404 error while fetching "RemoteEntry.mjs" disappeared, so it means it is able to fetch the MJS files.

D) Now, trying to navigate

- localhost:6001 = OK
- localhost:6001/shop = **ERR 404**
- localhost:6001/cart = **ERR 404**
- localhost:6001/about = **ERR 404**

and now I don't know what else I should configure, it is supposed that the MF configuration would understand the ROUTE /shop, and search for the proper URL which will be in the port :6002, but instead i'm constantly receiving a 404.

Am I having a wrong understanding about module federation? Is it going to support all the remote sites to be deployed under diferent sites? How can I achieve this if so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's happening if you try to go directly to localhost:6002 (or other MF port)?